# Can I run the same virtual machine in both vmware on a PC and vmware fusion on a Mac?

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion, cross-platform

Can one boot the same VM image in vmware workstation on a Windows XP machine AND in vmware fusion on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and also on linux.

Comment: I just finally took home my VMWare Workstation Win XP VM and ran it in VMWare Fusion on my mac. It's so beautiful! Happiness!

Answer (score 1):

Could also do it with virtualbox on win/mac/linux for free.

Comment: Correct.  And VirtualBox will run that VMWare instance that you have already created.